# App Store Guidelines

Tags: ios, app-store

We want to offer a ‘prize pot’ in our application, in that two or more players pay money into a prize fund, and the winner of the game gets this money. We were thinking of using PayPal to store the money, and then distribute a percentage to the winner (with us taking a small percentage). However, we’re not sure if this would infringe any of the guidelines surrounding iAP’s (in-App Purchases). Would this PayPal system be viable? Another possible approach would be to allow iAP’s to purchase virtual currency within the app, which the winner could redeem for real money via a PayPal transfer.

Furthermore, we believe this falls into the gambling sector, and according to the App Store guidelines:

> 20.5 - Apps that offer real money gaming (e.g. sports betting, poker, casino games, horse racing) or lotteries must have necessary licensing
>   and permissions in the locations where the App is used, must be
>   restricted to those locations, and must be free on the App Store. 
>   20.6 - Apps that use IAP to purchase credit or currency to use in conjunction with real money gaming will be rejected.

We have seen an application on the App Store that has similar functionality: Pact (Pact: Earn Cash for Exercise, Healthy Living, and Eating Right). Pact allows users to set up a ‘pact’ for example going to the gym 3 days in a week would earn you $1.50 each day you complete. Or else you are required to pay out $5 per day you miss. This app has recently been updated on April 1st, 2015 and it has similar functionality to our idea, in that users agree on a price to pay out (via PayPal) if they do not complete a task. Would our idea comply with the App Store rules?

Any suggestions are welcome, Thanks

Comment: Here's a good article explaining about guidelines for Android Google Play and Apple App Store https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/